# Python : Printing While Loop data set to a file

Tags: python, json, stdout

I am trying to take sensor data and plot it into a graph via JSON.
I would like to read the first 100 sensor values and create a file, after the 100, I want to replace the 1st with 101, 2nd with 102... etc so the file is constantly showing the latest 100 lines.

Say I have a random data stream coming in every 3 seconds to the standard output such as this..

```
from random import randint
import time

def loop():
        print(randint(100,200))

while True:
        loop()
        time.sleep(3)
```

How do I capture say 100 lines of the output, and write this data to a file?

Ideally the file should be replaced every ping by the new data.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, make a variable, increment it on each reading. A if statement on this variable to call a function for saving the data! No?

Comment: Your question is finally very broad. Appending to a file is easy, but replacing line 1 with new content, except in the very special case of lines of the very same binary length (beware of encoding for text), will require to write the file all over again. If you can afford keeping data in memory you could use a ring buffer (just a list in Python, resetting the index at a specified length), and maybe you can graph directly with python. Depending on your platform, you could also use other generic tools. Under Linux, i'd expand the file and use logrotate. You could emulate with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working crude solution :

```
from random import randint
import time

def loop():
    return randint(100,200)

def save_lst(lst):
    with open("mon_fich", "w") as f:
        f.write(", ".join(lst))

lst = list()
while True:
        lst.append(str(loop()))
        if len(lst)>=100:
            save_lst(lst)
            lst = list()
        time.sleep(0.001)
```

Comment: Thank-you:  A up? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping a counter variable, and reset it to 0 each time it hits 100 (modulo 100). This variable can be used as index to write to file:

```
i = 0
while True:
    write_file(i, loop(), filename)
    i += 1
    i = i % 100    

def write_file(line, input, filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    lines[line] = input   # <=== Replace the nth line with current input 
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
    out.close()
```

Comment: thank you! I wish I could figure out how to implement this lol

Comment: just need to plug in the above code (replacing your while loop) with your 'loop' function. Good luck!

Comment: for the line, input, filename area on the def write_file... can you give me an example? thank you!

Comment: It's there: write_file is called with i as line, loop() as input, and filename is whatever file you have that contains the 100 lines.